# How to Add product type donation into cart programmatically with custom amount(100 or 200 or something)?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using commerce_donate module and I want to add a product (type=donation) into cart programmatically with the amount set as per the user has already selected on some other page. On some custom form submit, I want to add this donation type product into cart in order to process the usual commerce order / checkout.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No code needed, just watch the video about "[Donations with Custom Line Item Types in Drupal Commerce](https://vimeo.com/31460419)". Some more details about it (= quote from that link):

> This screencast shows how to use a custom line item type to allow your customer to specify a user-defined amount to donate. The line item has a Donation Amount field on it, and we then create a product display node that uses that custom line item. Finally, we use a custom rule to update the "price" of the donation product to the amount the customer has chosen.

Comment: @Travis please check my edited version of your answer, attempting to improve your link-only answer. Feel free to further enhance it, of if ou don't like my edit at all simply perform a rollback ...

Comment: That looks and sounds great @Pierre.Vriens, thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: @TravisJohnston : ok, merci for "approve", but know that most of my edit (clarification) was a copy/paste from that link you first posted.

Answer (score 0):

In the form submit

```
function custom_form_submit($form,$form_state) {
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new(commerce_product_load($pid));
  commerce_cart_product_add($account->uid, $line_item);
  drupal_goto('cart');
}
```

Comment: This is adding the product but with the price added in the backend. How do I modify/update the price using this code. ?